# Expressjs / AngularJS: Error after implementing req-flash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I implemented req-flash like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/req-flash.
After doing this, the following error appears:

```
D:\_SOURCES\smfc\node_modules\req-flash\index.js:36
        if (options.locals) {
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'locals' of undefined
    at module.exports (D:\_SOURCES\smfc\node_modules\req-flash\index.js:36:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\_SOURCES\smfc\routes\index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\_SOURCES\smfc\app.js:15:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\_SOURCES\smfc\bin\www:7:11)
```

This is the part of index.js from req-flash:

```
module.exports = function(options) {
if (options.locals) {
    localsKey = options.locals;
}

return flash;
};
```

This is the intro of my app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./models/SupermarketGroups');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://smfc:smfc@ds011482.mlab.com:11482/smfc');

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('req-flash');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: '123' }));
app.use(flash());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem is that `flash` constructor function expects an `options` object to be **always passed in** meaning it expects a call like `flash({ /* expecting options object */ })`. It doesn't have a proper fallback if you do not pass anything which is what you are doing here `flash( /* you are not passing anything */ )`. Therefore, you best bet is what [Nivesh suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37256777/3928341), always pass in an options object and pass in an empty object if you don't have any options: `flash({})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there's a bug in the **req-flash** module.
For now you can use it like:

```
app.use(flash({}));
```

or
you can open req-flash in node-modules folder and update the index.js file with:

```
module.exports = function(options) {
if (options != null && options.locals) {
    localsKey = options.locals;
}

return flash;
};
```

**Explained:**
As it does not handle the undefined case for options, which we do not pass while instantiating like `app.use(flash())`. So, just put the check for options or pass an empty object to it.

Comment: The second option is probably not a good idea since any `npm install` will erase the changes.

Comment: yeah, well i have created a pull request for it though.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow. By the way: is this a proper solution to show errors to the user?

Comment: it simply stores the messages in the session, and clears it every time iff you send the response using ```res.send()``` or ```res.render()```. Better option is to use [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) which persists only for one request response cycle.

Comment: @etalon11 you can now update the ```req-flash``` module this issue has been fixed. Thanks, for pointing out the issue.

Comment: @Nivesh: Nice one! I saw your commit on github! Thanks.